# C# WinForm - Calculate Hours By Given 3 Number using Method in Class

Tags: c#, winforms, class, combobox

I'm creating a simple distance calculator. I have a window form with 2 combo boxes. The first combobox has the default place which is the Place1 and the second combobox has the value of Place1,Place2 and Place3.

Here's my code in my class.

```
public class classDistance
{
    public string Places { get; set; }
    public int DistanceKm { get; set; }

    public static void Hours() { 
        List<string> Cities = new List<string>();
        Cities.Add("Place1");
        Cities.Add("Place2");
        Cities.Add("Place3");

        List<int> DestinationKm = new List<int>();
        DestinationKm.Add(10); // Place1 = 10Km
        DestinationKm.Add(20); // Place2 = 20Km
        DestinationKm.Add(30); // Place3 = 30Km

        return;
    }
}

//Place1 has the speed of 80kmph.
```

And when the user click the button in the Form, it will calculate the Hours from the method class classDistance

```
// Inside my form
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

classDistance classname = new classDistance();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(comboBox1.Text == "Place1"){
        // call the method on the classname if the user click the button and calculate the hours   
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you made method `Hours()` static, you can simply call it by the class without creating any instance, like that:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClassDistance.Hours();
}
```

But now your method just fills the lists, not calculates hours actually.

**UPD:**
I think it's better off using dictionary for storing and getting data in your case:

```
var citiesDistance = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"Place1", 10},
    {"Place2", 20},
    {"Place3", 30}
};
```

Then, you can get appropriate value by the place's name, e.g.:

```
var name = "Place2";
var length = citiesDistance[name];
```

And after that, you can calculate hours, needed to get to the place:

```
var speed = 80;
var hours = length/speed;
```

Hope, I've understood your question correctly)

Comment: So sir, how can I calculate the hours now base on the Hours method()? :)

Comment: Sure sir. I will try this one :) I will let you know sir.

Comment: sir, when I click the button, nothing happens :_(

Comment: @mark did you define, how calculated hours supposed to be displayed? Do you show it on the form or, for example, in MessageBox?

Comment: I want to show it sir in my messageBox inside my form when the user clicks the button. :)

Comment: @mark in this case, you can call MessageBox inside your "button1_Click" method. Also you can change return type of "Hours" method from "void" to "double" and display the result in MessageBox. For example: 

double hours = ClassDistance.Hours();
MessageBox.Show("You will spend {0} hours.", hours.ToString());

You can get more on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984357(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Sir @goodday21, I am also wondering, I have combobox2 where if the user select the Place1,Place2,Place3, it will compute it just like your code above. It will compute from the combobox1 with the value of Place1. :(

Comment: @mark it'd be great if you create a new question and provide code, that you have) In this case another users could also give you a hand with your problem. It's hard to understand the situation without seeing concrete development)

Comment: Its okay sir. I fix it now. :) Thank you sir. And have a good day! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you have a list of places and a list of distances which aren't really related to each other.

What I would do is create a new class which contains both the place name and distance, e.g.:

```
public class Destination
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int DistanceKm  {get;set;}

    // ctor
    public Destination(String name, int distanceKm)
    {
        Name = name;
        DistanceKm = distanceKm;
    }

    public int getHours (int speed)
    {
        // do your calculation for the number of hours here
        return hours;
    }
}
```

You can then populate the destination with it's name and distance via the constructor, and use the getHours method to return the number of hours based on the speed you pass into it.

You could also create a List if you were handling multiple destinations

Comment: Is there a way I can do it in the same class @N Wright?

Comment: If you're wanting to do it in the same class, then you're probably better off using goodday21's suggestion of a dictionary :)